# Pattern in C# for loading data from large files with low memory impact

Tags: c#, json, memory

I have a scenario, where I load data from large files, e.g. json and I would like to keep the memory usage as low as possible. The other problem is that I would like to encapsulate the data loading from the processing part, so I can also implement an importer for xml for example.

If the data contains only a simple list it is quite easy, I can define an interface like this:

```
interface IImporter 
{
   IEnumerable<Data> LoadFrom(Stream stream);
}
```

And then I can implement it using the yield keyword:

```
class JsonImporter : IImporter
{
    public IEnumerable<Data> LoadFrom(Stream stream)
    {
        JsonReader reader = ...;
        ...
        while (...)
        {
            yield return new Data(reader.Read(...));
        }
    }
}
```

The advantage is that the memory impact is very low, if the JsonReader works efficiently only one Data object is in memory (depending on the processing). The negative side is that you cannot iterate over the enumerable twice depending on the situation.

But what happens if there is more complex data, e.g. first a header with some simple properties in json and then two array with totally different structure? In this case an IEnumerable does not work anymore. Do you have some patterns here or is there a framework for this. I think also about buffering and how the consumer can notify the producer that processing has been finished, so the stream (or the sql connection, ...) can be closed and disposed. Looking for some ideas.

Comment: Have you looked at `System.Xml.XmlReader`.  It is a good example of how to stream structured data.  Basically, you need to enumerate the structure in addition to the data so you know when you're transitioning from an array to the object containing the array, etc.  The outer code then only needs to keep a stack containing the context of where you are.  If you're building an object tree anyway, that's pointless, but if you're just scanning for some specific data, it works just fine.

Comment: The question is not how I can use the XmlReader efficiently. I know how to do it, but I have no working solution how to design the interface to realize the encapsulation from the storage technology.